# Prove the Limit $|S_n|=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

a) Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n = 0$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}|S_n| = 0$

The way I am looking at this is using the general principle: Let $(S_n)_n\in N$ be a sequence of real numbers which converges to $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and let $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ ($a \in I$) a function which is continuous at a. Then, $f(S_n)\to f(a)$  as $n\to\infty$.

Not sure if that is correct

Another question that is giving me trouble is

b) Prove that if $S_n = (-1)^n$ then $\lim |S_n|$ exists, but the $\lim S_n$ does not exist.

Comment: You could even write $\lim_{n}f(S_{n})=f(\lim_{n}S_{n})$ if $\lim_{n}S_{n}=a$ is known to exist and $f$ is continuous at $a$. This is a nice way to cut out some verbage. For (b), do you know that every subsequence of a convergent sequence also converges to the same limit as the original sequence?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from your general principle that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = 0$, then so is $\lim_{n \to \infty} |S_n|$.  However, the converse of this principle is not generally true, as is demonstrated by question b).

In order to answer the second part of a), I recommend taking a closer look at the definition of continuity.

In order to answer question b), note that
$$
\{S_n\}_{n=1}^\infty = \{-1,1,-1,1,\dots\}
$$
whereas
$$
\{|S_n|\}_{n=1}^\infty = \{1,1,1,1,\dots\}
$$
Why does the first sequence *not* have a limit?  Why does the second sequence have a limit?

Comment: Does what I've said help?  Are you now able to answer the question?  If not, feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: so would I say the reason the limit does not exist is because $S_n$ ossiclates between -1 and 1?

Comment: That is a valid reason... have you dealt with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit yet?